# Separating game logic and UI

Tags: java, android

This a simple game which only has three views: A TextView and two buttons (red and green button).

The player is supposed to press button that has the same color as the TextView background color. If the TextView Background color is Red, then the player should press the Red button.

Lets say that there are three different play modes:
Regular: You can play all day long.
Timelimit: you only have 3 seconds to answer.
Timetrial: answer correct as many times as possible during 30 seconds.

All modes share the same layout (xml).

Methods newGame() and newRound() will behave differently depending on which mode the player chooses.

“Regular” can have 2 states:
playing = color is presented and the program is waiting for user input
gave-wrong-answer = player pressed wrong button. Now that button is disabled. Player has to press the correct button to continue (newRound).

“Timelimit” always couns down from 3 to 0. When the user press a button the timer is always restarted and if the timer reaches 0, a newRound is triggered.

“Timetrial” will count down from 30 to 0 but will otherwise work like a “Regular” game.

All three modes share some common variables for example:
boolean isRed; //to know if the TextView isRed or not.

**How would this be organized / structured in terms of Activities and Classes?**

**Here are some actual code:**

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Normal game"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Timer game"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_red"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.041" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_play.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".PlayActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_colorbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_red"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_green"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

Button btn_normal;
Button btn_timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_normal = findViewById(R.id.btn_red);
    btn_timer = findViewById(R.id.btn_timer);

    btn_normal.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_timer.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayActivity.class);
    if (v == btn_normal) {
        intent.putExtra("GAME_MODE", "regular");
    } else if (v == btn_timer) {
        intent.putExtra("GAME_MODE", "timelimit");
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

PlayActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    static Button btn_red;
    static Button btn_green;
    static TextView txt_colorbox;
    Game game;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        txt_colorbox = findViewById(R.id.txt_colorbox);

        btn_red = findViewById(R.id.btn_red);
        btn_green = findViewById(R.id.btn_green);

        btn_red.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_green.setOnClickListener(this);

        String gameMode = getIntent().getStringExtra("GAME_MODE");

        if (gameMode.equals("regular")) {
            game = new RegularGame();
        } else if (gameMode.equals("timelimit")) {
            game = new TimelimitGame();
        }
        else if (gameMode.equals("timetrial")) {
            game = new TimetrialGame();
        }

        game.newGame();
        game.newRound();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn_red) {
            System.out.println("pressed Red");
        } else if (v == btn_green) {
            System.out.println("pressed Green");
        }
    }
}
```

Game.java:

```
public abstract class Game {

    boolean isRed;

    public void newGame() {
    }

    public void newRound() {
    }

}
```

RegularGame.java

```
public class RegularGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void newGame() {
        System.out.println("New game: regular mode");
    }

    @Override
    public void newRound() {
        System.out.println("New Round");
    }

}
```

TimelimitGame.java:

```
public class TimelimitGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void newGame() {
        System.out.println("New game: timelimit mode");
    }

    @Override
    public void newRound() {
        System.out.println("New Round");
    }

}
```

TimetrialGame.java:

```
public class TimetrialGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void newGame() {
        System.out.println("New game: timer mode");
    }

    @Override
    public void newRound() {
        System.out.println("New Round");
    }

}
```

**Am I supposed to provide the Context/Activity in the Game() constructor. So that I can access the TextView and the Buttons in that manner or should updateUI reside inside PlayActivity but gather information from Game class?**

Comment: You need to use interfaces. Create an interface containing the events that occur, and make PlayActivity implement it. Send this interface to the Game() constructor. Then, create some logic in Game to decide which method of the interface is to be called.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal like MVC ? can you provide some more information or maybe links to appropriet reading :)